# Log4j2: How to write the log to a folder inside of WEB-INF?

Tags: tomcat, logging, web-applications, log4j2, web-inf

I am using **Tomcat**. I want some **Log4j2** log to be written inside the `WEB-INF` folder of the web application. For example:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="MyLog" fileName="${????}/logs/MyLog.log">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad idea and not guaranteed to work for the following (incomplete) reasons:

- Your application server might not even unpack a WAR file, so that you don't have a file system to write to: An application can easily run from a WAR file.
- If you had an actual file system backed application: The next deployment of your application would wipe your log files
- For security reasons it's a good argument to not have web applications being able to overwrite themselves - granted, you could only make a single log directory writeable, but IMHO this is not a good strategy (and the permissions would easily be changed with the next deployment)

Rather allocate a specific log directory to your application server and use it for output. There you can configure log rotation etc. in a well known place, rather than all over the various web applications that might follow this style of configuration.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know the use case. For example, there is a file system and these logs are temporary, may be erased. I really need to do that, and your arguments, while well thought, do not apply in this particular case.

Comment: I still don't know the use case. None of the arguments you give mandate that the log files must be written in the app directory, so I stand by my argument to put them elsewhere. When the logs are indeed temporary, rather logroll them explicitly than relying on the next deployment to wipe them. Using best practices will also help the next maintainer.